# How to use printf and %s when there are color codes?

Tags: bash, shell-script, printf

I had these lines:

```
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
  printf "$fail_color Error - Function: $function, Line: $line_number \n"
  printf "do_test: Third parameter missing - expected result\n"
  exit 1
fi
```

This works fine and gives me the intended output of `Error - Function: words, Line: 94`

I then used ShellCheck and it recommended

```
printf "$fail_color Error - Function: $function, Line: $line_number \n
             ^––SC2059 Don't use variables in the printf format string. Use printf "..%s.." "$foo".
```

So I tried changing it to

```
  printf "%s Error - Function: %s, Line: %s \n", "$fail_color", "$function", "$line_number"
```

but now the output shows the color code details instead of the color:

```
\033[31;1m, Error - Function: words,, Line: 94 
,do_test: Third parameter missing - expected result
```

Related - is there a better way to name the strings other than multiple `%s`'s?

Detail - the color are defined this way:

```
fail_color="\033[31;1m"
pass_color="\033[32;1m"
color_end="\033[0m"
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5413029/3776858

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the contents of the variables and how they're being set.

Comment: Sure. Added more on how the color variables are set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like Cyrus's answer, but this syntax also works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

fail_color=$'\033[31;1m'
color_end=$'\033[0m'
function="foo"
line_number="42"

printf "%sError - Function: %s, Line: %d%s\n" "$fail_color" "$function" "$line_number" "$color_end"
```

And ShellCheck says "It all looks good!". :)

Comment: This is the only that has worked for me so far.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Thanks! But it's odd that Cyrus's code didn't work. What version of bash are you using; FWIW, I'm using 4.1.5(1), with a ShellShock patch.

Comment: @PM2Ring this solution is not working with shell. Can you please assist?

Comment: @ekassis "not working" is very vague. What does it do? Are you using Bash? If so, which version?  What terminal are you using?

Comment: Note https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371827/5132 of course.

Answer (score 10):

```
fail="\033[31;1m"
color_end="\033[0m"
func="foo"  # (renamed this variable to avoid confusion with function keyword)
line_number="42"

printf "%bError - Function: %s, Line: %d%b\n" "$fail" "$func" "$line_number" "$color_end"
```

Output:

```
Error - Function: foo, Line: 42
```

---

Tested with Ubuntu 11.04 (bash 4.2.8(1)-release), Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (bash 4.3.11(1)-release), RHEL 5.1 (bash 3.1.17(1)-release), RHEL 6.0 (bash 4.1.2(1)-release), RHEL 7.0 (bash 4.3.11(1)-release) and Solaris 11 (bash 4.1.9(1)-release)

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Maybe becuase I am using an include file for the color codes.  However PM 2Ring's answer did work for me.

Comment: This code worked for me on Fedora 21:GNU bash, version 4.3.33(1)-release

Answer (score 0):

The [`printf(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/printf.1.html) man says:

> ```
> %b     ARGUMENT as a string with '\' escapes interpreted, except
>        that octal escapes are of the form \0 or \0NNN
> ```

So, it`s works:
[image: example]

Answer (score -2):

The variable `"$fail_color"` contains one too many, or one too few backslashes before the `033`, try changing it or removing the `""` to have it debackslashified.

```
\033
```

is supposed to be the ESC character (ASCII 27 decimal, 033 octal).

Comment: They work the other way and without them I get `$ ./17_number_letter_counts.sh 
033[31;1m, Error - Function: words,, Line: 94 
,do_test: Third parameter missing - expected result
`

Comment: OK, try adding a backslash instead of removing one - it is a little difficult to correct the code without actually seeing it or being able to call it oneself.  Please also check the number of backslashes before the `[` and `;` characters.

Comment: I tried adding one, e.g. changing `fail_color="\033[31;1m"` to `fail_color="\\033[31;1m"` but I got the same error.

Comment: I meant trying also `fail_color="\\033\[31\;1m` (something like this has worked for me in the past) but I see that you have now found a different solution.