# How to solve compability problem the code printf in bash and sh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I write a basic script which it has colourful lines in it.

```
#!/bin/bash

g="\e[32m"
_0="\e[0m"

printf "$g name $_0"
```

The script runs normally but at [shellcheck.net](https://shellcheck.net) I got this message: `Don't use variables in the printf format string`.

Another problem when I convert my script to `#!/bin/sh` my script doesn't run correctly, giving this output:

```
\e[32m name \e[0m
```

I used `echo -e` but this time `sh` said that `-e` wasn't supported. How do I write a common line of code to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: This is almost https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/205497/5132 again.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it works with ```bash``` but not with  ```sh``` Is there a way that work with both?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this, will work either on bash or sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# \e not supported by POSIX; use \033 (octal) instead.
g=$(printf '\033[32m')
_0=$(printf '\033[0m')

printf '%s name %s foo' "$g" "$_0"
```

Comment: Thanks that's the anwser I was looking for! Plus, why shellcheck.net says```Don't use variables in the printf format string.``` Is there a solid reason?

Comment: @AhmetMehmet It makes it very difficult to print strings contains backslashes and percentage signs for starters.

Comment: To print to a variable in `bash`, use e.g. `printf -v _0 '\033[0m'`. No need for the command substitution.

Comment: Thanks I see. Is there a site to show all characters octal forms like \033 I find different things?

Comment: You can check [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Or use `man ascii`.  And https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371827/5132 gives one reason that this answer is as it is.